# OracleSQL refer to columns just created

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to refer to columns created in the same `SELECT`

```
SELECT 2*a as a2,
       3*a2 as a6
FROM ...
```

I am aware that I could use a nested query, but with many variables created after each other this seems tedious.

Comment: No, You can not. Instead, You can use the expression of a2 inside a6 or sub-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not refer to the alias in the same `SELECT` clause. It is SQL standard behavior, and it prevents ambiguities.

There are two options as I have mentioned in the comment also.

-- Use expression of the a2 in a6

```
SELECT 2*a as a2,
       3*(2*a) as a6
FROM ...
```

-- OR use the sub-query

```
SELECT a2, 3*a2 as a6 FROM
(SELECT 2*a as a2
       --3*a2 as a6
FROM ...)
```

Comment: that's what I was afraid of but so be it!